# In sql how do you loop through singleton values in an xquery for an xml?

Tags: sql-server, xml, loops, t-sql, xquery

This seems like it should be something really simple to do but I've tried numerous ways and consistently get errors and my google-fu is failing me. I am shredding xml files in T-SQL and the xml files can have anywhere from 1 to thousands of items. I just need to loop through the items so I can pull the various data. An acceptable solution would be to simply throw all the item date into a temporary table with the nodes as the column headings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
declare @x as xml
set @x = '<root>
    <item>
        <itemCharacteristicA>this</itemCharacteristicA>
        <itemCharacteristicB>part of this</itemCharacteristicB>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemCharacteristicA>that</itemCharacteristicA>
        <itemCharacteristicB>part of that</itemCharacteristicB>
    </item>
</root>'

declare @i int = 1

while @x.value('(/root/item[@i]/itemCharacteristicA)[1]','varchar(50)') is not null
begin
select @x.value('(/root/item[@i]/itemCharacteristicA)[1]','varchar(50)') CharA, @x.value('(/root/item[@i]/itemCharacteristicB)[1]','varchar(50)') CharB
set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively simple to do by using XML data type `.nodes()` and `.value()` methods.

It is called shredding, i.e. conversion of XML into a rectangular relational structure. No need to do any loops.

> SQL

```
declare @x as xml
set @x = '<root>
    <item>
        <itemCharacteristicA>this</itemCharacteristicA>
        <itemCharacteristicB>part of this</itemCharacteristicB>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemCharacteristicA>that</itemCharacteristicA>
        <itemCharacteristicB>part of that</itemCharacteristicB>
    </item>
</root>';

SELECT c.value('(itemCharacteristicA/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS itemCharacteristicA
    , c.value('(itemCharacteristicB/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS itemCharacteristicB
FROM @x.nodes('/root/item') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| itemCharacteristicA | itemCharacteristicB |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| this                | part of this        |
| that                | part of that        |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! 

I knew there was a simple solution and I ws going a bit crazy since I was having such a hard time finding it. I even tried something very similar to this solution, but I was missing the text() in the .value().

Comment: @dehuman8, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.